# How to show wrong password message during authenication

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, authentication

I am using windows authentication for log in to  websites.when  we enter wrong password it is again showing the same log in dialogue .I want to alert user as wrong username/password.Please help me how to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can actually accomplish this using windows authentication.

For the user name portion, if you think about it for a moment, how would you actually know they entered the "wrong" user name? If I enter domain\jsmith but I intended to enter domain\jsmithe, both could actually be valid users.

For both the user name and password, the active directory domain controller(s) (which is what actually authenticates the user name/password combination) will basically only tell you that the credentials didn't authenticate - not the specific reason.

On a side note, even if the domain controller did tell you that the password was incorrect for the given user name, ***I would strongly discourage you from presenting that to the user*** as it can be used for malicious intent. Most commercial sites will not tell you if the password is incorrect for exactly this reason.